# Creating aws_dynamodb_table with terraform and localstack takes forever

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, localstack

I was testing how to setup terraform+localstack with the following configuration file https://github.com/wentao-daommo/aws-local/blob/master/local.tf

When I run command

```
terraform apply --auto-approve
```

The log shows something like this forever!

```
aws_dynamodb_table.table_1: Still creating... [26m51s elapsed]
```

I think something is wrong that causes table creation taking so long, and it never completed.

Anyone know this?

Answer (score 0):

By default DynamoDB as well as all other services on `localstack` are exposed on port `4566`. However your script uses different port `dynamodb       = "http://localhost:4569"`. Please change it to:

```
dynamodb       = "http://localhost:4566"
```

Similarly all other services are set to non-default port in your terraform script.

Comment: Thanks for help! I turned out the port isn't the issue. In the docker-compose file, I didn't start the dynamodb service. That is why.

Comment: @WentaoZheng Docker compose for localstack also uses [4566](https://github.com/localstack/localstack/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) port.

Comment: Yes. But in my example, I'm using localstack version 10.5 which still uses separate ports for different services.

Comment: @WentaoZheng You should have specified this in your question rather then omit this important fact.