# Localstack creation of dynamoDB via terraform "still creating..." forever?

Tags: docker, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, localstack

Trying to create a dynamoDB table via terraform within a Localstack environment running in a docker container. I have the following terraform file:

```
provider "aws" {
  region                  = "us-east-1"  # Change to your desired region
  access_key              = "test"       # Access key for LocalStack
  secret_key              = "test"       # Secret key for LocalStack
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_requesting_account_id = true

  endpoints {
    dynamodb = "https://localhost:4566"  # LocalStack DynamoDB endpoint
  }
}


resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "users_table" {
  name           = "UserProfileTable"
  #billing_mode   = "PROVISIONED"  # Or use "PAY_PER_REQUEST" for on-demand capacity
  read_capacity  = 5
  write_capacity = 5
  hash_key = "UserID"
  range_key = "PostID"

  attribute {
    name = "UserID"
    type = "N"
  }

  attribute {
    name = "PostID"
    type = "N"
  }



  tags = {
    Name    = "dynamodb-table-1"
    Environment = "production"
  }
}
```

I run the `localstack start -d` and confirm the container is running. I navigate to the directory where the main.tf file sits. I run `terraform init` and then `terraform apply`. I get the following response:

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # aws_dynamodb_table.users_table will be created
  + resource "aws_dynamodb_table" "users_table" {
      + arn              = (known after apply)
      + billing_mode     = "PROVISIONED"
      + hash_key         = "UserID"
      + id               = (known after apply)
      + name             = "UserProfileTable"
      + range_key        = "PostID"
      + read_capacity    = 5
      + stream_arn       = (known after apply)
      + stream_label     = (known after apply)
      + stream_view_type = (known after apply)
      + tags             = {
          + "Environment" = "production"
          + "Name"        = "dynamodb-table-1"
        }
      + tags_all         = {
          + "Environment" = "production"
          + "Name"        = "dynamodb-table-1"
        }
      + write_capacity   = 5

      + attribute {
          + name = "PostID"
          + type = "N"
        }
      + attribute {
          + name = "UserID"
          + type = "N"
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
╷
│ Warning: AWS account ID not found for provider
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws"],
│   on dynamoDB-definition.tf line 1, in provider "aws":
│    1: provider "aws" {
│ 
│ See https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#skip_requesting_account_id for implications.
╵

Do you want to perform these actions?
  Terraform will perform the actions described above.
  Only 'yes' will be accepted to approve.
```

I type 'yes' and then get stuck on `aws_dynamodb_table.users_table: Still creating...` forever.

I saw [in this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65867193/creating-aws-dynamodb-table-with-terraform-and-localstack-takes-forever) that they needed to like initialize the dynamoDB services. I don't know how to do this, and the internet suggests this isn't necessary. Why isn't the table ever created?

I have included the version of the various components below. Not sure if relevant.

`Localstack --version`: 3.1.0
`awslocal --version`: aws-cli/1.32.31 Python/3.11.0 Darwin/23.2.0 botocore/1.34.31
`terraform --version`: Terraform v1.7.2 on darwin_arm64 + provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v5.34.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is steps to make Terraform run successfully:

1. (Optional) Try using AWS provided image [DynamoDB Local](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.DownloadingAndRunning.html). Create Docker Compose file `docker-compose.yml`:

   ```yaml
   version: '3.8'
   services:
     dynamodb-local:
       command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb"
       image: "amazon/dynamodb-local:latest"
       container_name: dynamodb-local
       ports:
         - "4566:8000"
   ```
2. Change endpoint configuration in `.tf` file:

   ```
   endpoints {
       dynamodb = "http://localhost:4566"  # Use HTTP protocol here!
   }
   ```
3. Run in terminal:

   ```bash
   localstack start -d # or docker-compose up -d
   terraform init
   terraform apply
   ```

   Ignore `AWS account ID not found for provider` warning and type `yes`.
   Now you should see:

   ```
   Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
   ```

Comment: What does step 1 do? I already have localstack running in docker and the terraform commands should create the dynamodb instance in that env. What additional/different thing is happening when I create the `docker-compose.yml` file? Does the dynamodb instance get its *own* docker container in this case? Instead of being in the localstack container? What is the benefit of this?

Comment: Its optional step you can ignore, this step make sure you have proper DynamoDB and problems not with  DynamoDB setup with localstack

Answer (score 0):

The only change needed in your Terraform configuration was this:

```
provider "aws" {
  region                  = "us-east-1"  # Change to your desired region
  access_key              = "test"       # Access key for LocalStack
  secret_key              = "test"       # Secret key for LocalStack
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  skip_requesting_account_id = true

  endpoints {
    dynamodb = "http://localhost:4566"  # Use http endpoint here
  }
}
```

You can analyze the LocalStack logs to see your DynamoDB table being created:

```bash
2024-02-01T07:51:32.556  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_0] localstack.request.aws     : AWS dynamodb.CreateTable => 200
2024-02-01T07:51:32.571  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_1] localstack.request.aws     : AWS dynamodb.DescribeTable => 200
2024-02-01T07:51:32.583  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_0] localstack.request.aws     : AWS dynamodb.DescribeTable => 200
2024-02-01T07:51:32.592  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_1] localstack.request.aws     : AWS dynamodb.DescribeContinuousBackups => 200
2024-02-01T07:51:32.609  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_0] localstack.request.aws     : AWS dynamodb.DescribeTimeToLive => 200
2024-02-01T07:51:32.624  INFO --- [   asgi_gw_1] localstack.request.aws     : AWS dynamodb.ListTagsOfResource => 200
```

LocalStack uses DynamoDB Local under the hood, and on top of it LocalStack has support for global tables, multi-accounts and multi-region namespacing, integration with Kinesis and DynamoDB Streams, as well as persistence.

Comment: Ok this fixed it but I am confused. 1. Why can I not use https? Isn't this more secure? How can I modify it s/t I *can* use HTTPS? 2. (More importantly) why did this work if the docker logs state that `2024-02-01 07:30:00 2024-02-01T12:30:00.510  INFO --- [-functhread4] hypercorn.error            : Running on https://0.0.0.0:4566`? If logs themselves say it is running on `https://localhost:4566`, why does only `http://localhost:4566` actually work?